# Which proprietary video driver do I need for a VTK Rad7K 64P graphics card?

Tags: graphics, radeon

Can anyone tell me which driver to use for video device listed in screen? I don't know but model number on box when I purchased card is [VTKRad7K64P](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814129042), my computer is running REALLY slow.

![lspci]/home/doug/Desktop/ubuntu.JPG

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Unfortunately, your screenshot did not make it into your question; it appears that you are using the location of the picture on your machine instead of a URL you uploaded it to. Could you fix this so we can see the picture, or add the missing details in text so we can help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your card is [Radeon 7000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_R100), it's an old card (do not confuse it with the [Radeon HD7000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_7000_Series), which is a much newer card). Your card has been declared obsolete by ATI/AMD and is not supported by the proprietary drivers any more. The good news is that it should be supported by the [open source drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver). See if hardware acceleration is enabled (from that page):

> Testing The Driver
>
> To look for boot messages/errors, check
>
> dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
>
> To see your OpenGL information, you can run the commands below. Make
>   sure your OpenGL renderer string does not say "software rasterizer" or
>   "llvmpipe" because that would mean you have no 3D hardware
>   acceleration:
>
> sudo apt-get install mesa-utils LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
>   LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo

If it is enabled, and your computer is still slow, then that is probably due to it being old - Radeon 7000 is 14 years old now. Ubuntu (with Unity desktop) is too much for such a system, I suggest trying Xubuntu or one of the other lightweight distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am noop to ubuntu. Last night I removed card in question above and installed an ASUS V9400 AGP card, that I was using on XP. I got Ubuntu to boot up to purple screen, but nothing else is there. The mouse moves, and I can right click and go into "all setting", and I can open and close "terminal", with no problem, I just do not have the "launch" bar on left of screen nor the bar at the top of the screen, other than that everything is great. Can you help me with that?

Comment: That could be a graphics driver or configuration issue, which Ubuntu are you using? Do you see the same issue when booting the 14.04 livecd (eg [ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso))?